# How do we customize the centroids in k-means clustering

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, k-means

I am trying to implement k-means clustering on Spark using Python and i want to specify the initial centroids instead of taking 'random' or 'k-means++'. I want to pass an RDD which contains the list of centroids. How should I do this in Pyspark.

Comment: [Cross Validated Stack Exchange](http://stats.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @jww I didn't find any related question posted in the given link.